# die attach package void analysis in French

Tags: traduction, anglais, terminologie

I'm having issues to make an accurate translation of this sentence. This is a word/phrase that is a bit complex to translate, so I would like to explain a bit about it. It's compound of 3 separate items:

---

- The **package** is the enclosure for one or more chips - or dies - (see packaging in [Integrated Circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_circuit)). Because a package can contain one or more chips I think it's necessary to keep the translation in a way to clarify this (e.g. that the chip or die is contained in the package). Nevertheless, I found some suggestions. Electropedia recommends using [boîtier](http://www.electropedia.org/iev/iev.nsf/display?openform&ievref=521-05-31). And the wikipedia community seems also ok with the word [package](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(%C3%A9lectronique)) as it is:

> ... On utilise aussi le terme packaging, dérivé de l'anglais. ...

---

- A **die attachment** is the actual chip, separated or whole in the wafer. Eletropedia recommends using [puce or pastille](http://www.electropedia.org/iev/iev.nsf/display?openform&ievref=521-05-30). I've also found in wikipedia that [die](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Die) as it stands could also be acceptable in french:

> ... En électronique, le die est la partie élémentaire d'une tranche de silicium (wafer) en cours de fabrication. Elle correspond au circuit qui sera ensuite découpé et que l’on appellera une puce, ou circuit intégré. ...

---

- Finally **void analysis** can be understood as the "analysis of voids" that can be found inside the die. There could be one or multiple voids that could cover some or much of the area of the die. Electropedia suggest [vide](http://www.electropedia.org/iev/iev.nsf/display?openform&ievref=395-07-36) for void. I would guess that a good translation for this part is: *Analyse de vides*

---

Other references:

- [System in package - système dans un boîtier](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_in_package)
- [Composant électronique](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composant_%C3%A9lectronique)
- [Circuit intégré](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_int%C3%A9gr%C3%A9)
- [Encapsulation (électronique)](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(%C3%A9lectronique))

---

After going through all these terms and suggestions I've came up with a list of possible translations for the sentence as a whole, but I'm not sure if any of these could portray the true meaning of the sentence, or if they could mislead the reader to think something else?

- Analyse de vides dans le die du package
- Analyse de vides à l'intérieur du puce de package
- Analyse de vides dans le puce de package
- Analyse de vides dans le puce du boîtier
- Analyse de vides sous le puce du package
- Analyse de vides sous le composant du package
- Analyse de vides de composant sous package
- Analyse de vides de die sous package
- Analyse de vides de matrice du package

Can any of these make sense to what I want to achieve/mean?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of "Analyze des vides", I would say "Analyse des inclusions gazeuses".

For "die attach package", according to the context, I propose the following translations:

- For a single chip in the wafer: "du circuit intégré",
- For the whole wafer: "de la matrice de circuits intégrés" (you may also use the anglicism "wafer")
- for the package: "de la puce electronique".

*Depending whether "voids" are located in the material or at the surface, you can replace the preposisitions "du/de"(of) by "dans"(in) or "sur"(on)*